# php warning mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem while connecting php with mysql.
Mysql server and client is running fine.And mysql socket file is in

```
/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But while connecting like :

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
```

It says

```
Socket operation on non-socket (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock)
```

Any clue?

Comment: Answer to your issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477985/1514026

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions at all, instead use mysqli or PDO, as written in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL is running without a socket file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477552/mysql-is-running-without-a-socket-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","","");
```

Comment: Pointless if the server isn't configured to allow TCP connections, which most aren't, by default.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your actual MySQL Socket File is in a different location than where PHP is expecting it to be.

Do a `phpinfo();` and see what the location of the socket file should be, per PHP.

You can then symlink it from where it is currently located.