# Can't create a new instance of MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I try to make a new instance of a MySQLi object to connect to a local database, I get the following error:

`Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/login_system/php/dbconnect.php on line 9`

Here is the code for my file:

```
<?php
        //Database credentials
        $server   = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = 'root'; //NOT secure, used this as a demo
        $database = 'login';

        //Create the database object
        $db = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

        //Was there errors?
        if($db->connect_errno > 0)
        {
                die("Error connecting to database " . $database + "\nErrors: " + $db->connect_error);
        }
?>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Mysql server is running?

Comment: Yes, my server is running. Apache, MySQL, and FTP all started successfully.

Comment: @JasonAjmo: What does the following output?: `var_dump(ini_get('mysql.default_socket'));`

Comment: @AmalMurali It outputs `string(31) "/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock"`

Comment: You compile and install PHP by yourself? and did not install mysql module?

Comment: @PasteBT I installed XAMPP. I'm running Linux Mint.

Comment: follow this link it contains what might help
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871304/2891986

Answer (score 4):

You need to connect to "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost".

There is an explanation here: https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1

In short your server is configured so MySQL listens to 127.0.0.1 but not localhost.